# Can't access routerParams outside of <app>

Tags: angularjs, router

I have a component in my header that is kind of static on the page. and outside of the `<app>`.

I would like to know if it is possible for this component to get the router parameters, or if I have to manually check from window.location and split the string with some regex.

The app I work on do not implement some kind of service to get those parameters, so I am asking for an angularjs native way if there is.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: angular 2+ question ?